# Using jQuery Ajax to calculate per table row

Tags: php, ajax, rows, calculation

I am just getting into Ajax/jQuery and was hoping someone could help me figure this out.

I have a table with multiple rows that is generated from php.
On each TR row I have a 3 fields (days, hrs, mins) that I want to use to calculate time.
The variables are POSTed to an ajax.php file for the calculations.
and the response should populate the #totalhrs input field per table row.

I have it working so far, but only on the first row, and only if I make my calls to that specific set of IDs.

I believe the way I'm going about it is pretty ugly,
and I was thinking there has to be a better more efficient way.

Thanks in advance

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".task").click(function() {
    var days=$("#aaa_1_days").val();
    var hrs=$("#aaa_1_hrs").val();
    var mins=$("#aaa_1_mins").val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'ajax.php',
      data:{days:days, hrs:hrs, mins:mins},
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data) {
        $("#aaa_1_totalhrs").val(data);
      }
    });
  });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='aaa_1_days'      id='aaa_1_days'     value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='aaa_1_hrs'       id='aaa_1_hrs'      value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='aaa_1_mins'      id='aaa_1_mins'     value='' min='0' max='45' step='15' /></td>
       <td><input type='text'    class='task' name='aaa_1_totalhrs'  id='aaa_1_totalhrs' value='' min='0' readonly /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='bbb_2_days'      id='bbb_2_days'     value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='bbb_2_hrs'       id='bbb_2_hrs'      value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='bbb_2_mins'      id='bbb_2_mins'     value='' min='0' max='45' step='15' /></td>
       <td><input type='text'    class='task' name='bbb_2_totalhrs'  id='bbb_2_totalhrs' value='' min='0' readonly /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='ccc_3_days'      id='ccc_3_days'     value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='ccc_3_hrs'       id='ccc_3_hrs'      value='' min='0'  /></td>
       <td><input type='number'  class='task' name='ccc_3_mins'      id='ccc_3_mins'     value='' min='0' max='45' step='15' /></td>
       <td><input type='text'    class='task' name='ccc_3_totalhrs'  id='ccc_3_totalhrs' value='' min='0' readonly /></td>
   </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

$post_days = $_POST['days'];
$post_hrs = $_POST['hrs'];
$post_mins = $_POST['mins'];

if($post_days){$days = $post_days*8;} else $days = 0;
if($post_hrs){$hrs = $post_hrs;} else $hrs = 0;

if($post_mins=='15'){$mins = 0.25;}
else if($post_mins=='30'){$mins = 0.5;}
else if($post_mins=='45'){$mins = 0.75;}
else $mins = 0;

$total = ($days+$hrs+$mins);

echo $total;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` to get required values from input-boxes . Then , use `$(this).closest("tr")` to get closest `tr` from input-box where change event has been occur and finally use `.find("yourclassname")` to get input values.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".task").change(function() {
    //get closest tr
    var selector = $(this).closest("tr");
    //use .find to get requred inputs
    var days = selector.find(".days").val();
    var hrs = selector.find(".hrs").val();
    var mins = selector.find(".mins").val();
    console.log(days + " " + hrs + " " + mins)
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      data: {
        days: days,
        hrs: hrs,
        mins: mins
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        selector.find(".totalhrs").val(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  <!--use class-->
    <td><input type='number' class='task days' name='aaa_1_days' id='aaa_1_days' value='' min='0' /></td>
    <td><input type='number' class='task hrs' name='aaa_1_hrs' id='aaa_1_hrs' value='' min='0' /></td>
    <td><input type='number' class='task mins' name='aaa_1_mins' id='aaa_1_mins' value='' min='0' max='45' step='15' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='task totalhrs' name='aaa_1_totalhrs' id='aaa_1_totalhrs' value='' min='0' readonly /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='number' class='task days' name='bbb_2_days' id='bbb_2_days' value='' min='0' /></td>
    <td><input type='number' class='task hrs' name='bbb_2_hrs' id='bbb_2_hrs' value='' min='0' /></td>
    <td><input type='number' class='task mins' name='bbb_2_mins' id='bbb_2_mins' value='' min='0' max='45' step='15' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' class='task totalhrs' name='bbb_2_totalhrs' id='bbb_2_totalhrs' value='' min='0' readonly /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```